Facebook Graph API: How to set up On Behalf Of relationship with a client business?
Working on a product for posting content on user's facebook pages and managing their product catalogs/ad accounts via API calls. As far as I understand, in order to manage client assets from my app, I need to have an On Behalf Of relationship between my business account and the client's business account. This however seems impossible, considering that their own documentation mentions edges that do not exist anymore (specifically /{business_id}/managed_businesses).
I tried using user access tokens from Facebook Login directly but that doesn't seem to work, and have been looking at documentation which seems to be outdated and not accurate anymore.
My question is: has anyone managed to set this up recently? What am I missing?

After searching on this topic for a while, for my use case the solution was to implement the Facebook Login process in the frontend, get the User Access Token from it and then use it to make requests to Meta.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
